# Should I consider serialization issues when designing abstract classes?

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization, abstract-class

Generally this question comes from Eclipse suggesting to add a serial version UID on an abstract class.

Since the class is abstract instances of this class will never exist thus they will never be serialized (only derived classes will be).

So my question is it safe to place a `@SuppressWarnings("serial")` on an abstract class who's extenders will be serialized (and they will have serialVersionUIDs) ?

Also any other issues to be careful about when designing an abstract class who's extenders will be serialized are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every serialisable class needs a `serialVersionUID`. If an object is of a runtime type that itself extends a serialisable class, then there are two `serialVersionUID`s involved. So, yes you need it, unless you decide not to support serialisation across versions (like Swing).

Comment: You mean that both the UIDs of a parent and child serializable classes matter when deserializing ?

Comment: @Simeon Yes, every serialisable class.

Answer (score 4):

Don't make the abstract class Serializable, if not absolutely needed (if it has no state). You will need to maintain the class serialized form for life and provide backwards compatibility for the previous versions of serialized forms. But you still need to provide a no parameter constructor in case the extending classes implements Serializable by themselves.

If you decide to implement the Serializable interface, you need the serial version uid on the abstract class, otherwise the serialized forms of extending classes will break when a new version of the abstract class is released.