# Serialization with Super class and Sub class

Tags: java

My doubt is using Scenario 1 it is possible to achieve serialization . If I extend one abstract class which is serializable  by many sub classes means , is this possible to achieve ?. As I tried with Scenario 2.

Serializable will be applicable for all beans or not,Please help me.

**my doubt scenario 1 and scenario 2 will be same or different.**

//method to send message  :::  sendMsgs(SerializableObject)

Scenario 1:

```
public class EmailMaster implements Serializable 
{
// setters and getters
}
```

Scenario 2:

```
public abstract class MessageBean implements Serializable 
{ 
}

//whether EmailMaster and EmailEvent  will become serializable ?

public class EmailMaster extends MessageBean 
{
// setters and getters



public class EmailEvent extends MessageBean 
{
// setters and getters
}
```

Comment: Check out the second comment
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257380/should-i-consider-serialization-issues-when-designing-abstract-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Serializable emailMaster = new EmailMaster();
```

If it works then `EmailMaster` **is-a** `Serializable`. AFAIK, that definitely should work.

Comment: my doubt scenario 1 and  scenario 2 will be same or different.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. But, they are different as in the first one you don't have `MessageBean` and in the other you have it.

Comment: I am having method sendMsgs(MessageBean mb) which accepts only serializable object so I used second scenario.So which is correct or not ? Please help me.

Comment: `sendMsgs(MessageBean mb)` why doesn't that have `Serializable` instead, if it only accepts `Serializable` object. But it should be fine because you know `MessageBean` is `Serializable`.

Answer (score 2):

This should be `Serialilzable`. **When you extend `MessageBean`, all extending classes of `MessageBean` be default inherit the `Serializable` interface from `MessageBean` abstract class.**

I would advice to have unique `serialVersionUID` assigned in each extending(sub) classes.

**EDIT: From Searialization perspective, `scenario1` and `sceanrio2` are not different** but theoretically they are different as you are having an additional abstract class in `sceario2`, which can have more methods/attributes, which will also get available to the `EmailMaster` class.

**In both the scenarios: `sendMsgs(SerializableObject)` should work.** Make a decision between sceanrio1 and scenario2 based on the need of abstract class in between. **If you don't need the abstract class for any other purpose, go with scenario1.**

Answer (score 2):

`Serializable` is inherited by all the subclasses of the abstract class as for any other interface:

If A implements `Serializable`, whatever class extends A will be `Serializable`

So both Scenarios will work but **in any case a concrete Serializable class must have a no-args constructor**. See the following [**Serializable Javadoc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the
>   java.io.Serializable interface. Classes that do not implement this
>   interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized.
>   All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable. The
>   serialization interface has no methods or fields and serves only to
>   identify the semantics of being serializable.
>
> To allow subtypes of non-serializable classes to be serialized, the
>   subtype may assume responsibility for saving and restoring the state
>   of the supertype's public, protected, and (if accessible) package
>   fields. **The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class
>   it extends has an accessible no-arg constructor to initialize the
>   class's state**. It is an error to declare a class Serializable if this
>   is not the case. The error will be detected at runtime.

Moreover, regarding the `Serial Version ID` of the object:

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a
>   version number, called a **serialVersionUID, which is used during
>   deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized
>   object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with
>   respect to serialization**. If the receiver has loaded a class for the
>   object that has a different serialVersionUID than that of the
>   corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an
>   InvalidClassException. A serializable class can declare its own
>   serialVersionUID explicitly by declaring a field named
>   "serialVersionUID" that must be static, final, and of type long:

```
ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
```

> **If a serializable class does not explicitly declare a serialVersionUID, then the serialization runtime will calculate a
>   default serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects
>   of the class, as described in the Java(TM) Object Serialization
>   Specification**. However, it is strongly recommended that all
>   serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since
>   the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class
>   details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can
>   thus result in unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during
>   deserialization.