# Is my inheritance code correct?

Tags: java, inheritance

So basically, I am doing this school project, and I have a super class called Person, and two subclasses (employees and clients) which extends class Person. When I run eighter subclass and for example when I add an employee, store the data in a .dat file, exit the program and re-run it, all the data stored before is set to a blank String. I hink that this is coming from the parameterless constructor in class Person, but that is the way I learnt to code it.

Super class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Person{
String name, sname, dob, address, tel, mob;

public Person(){
    name = "";  //I tried removing these statements, but then the data returned was null
    sname = "";
    dob = "";
    address = "";
    tel = ""; 
    mob = "";
}

public Person(String name, String sname, String dob, String address, String tel, String mob){
    this.name = name;
    this.sname = sname;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.address = address;
    this.tel = tel;
    this.mob = mob;
}
```

Sub-class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Employee extends Person implements Serializable{
private String empid;

private String valn = "[a-zA-Z ]+";
private String vala = "[a-zA-Z0-9, ]+";
private String valt = "[2][17][0-9]{6}";
private String valm = "[79][9][0-9]{6}";
private String valmm = "[7][7][0-9]{6}";
private String chkeid = "[0-9]{4}[E]";

public Employee(){
    super();
    empid = "";
}

public Employee(String name, String sname,  String dob, String address, String tel,        String mob,String empid){
    super(name, sname, dob, address, tel, mob); 
    this.empid = empid;
}

public void setId(String empid){
    this.empid = empid;
}

public String getId(){
    return empid;
}

public String ToString(){
    return "Emloyee Name: " + name + " " + sname + " " + 
    "\nAddress: " + address +
    "\nDate of Birth: " + dob +
    "\nTelephone Number: " + tel +
    "\nMobile Number:  " + mob +
    "\nEmployee ID:  " + empid;
}//Other methods...
```

Code for file saving:

```
File stock = new File("C:/Users/david/Desktop/Stock.dat");
    File employee = new File("C:/Users/david/Desktop/Employee.dat");
    File clients = new File("C:/Users/david/Desktop/Clients.dat");

    try{
        if(stock.exists() == true){
            FileInputStream inFileStream = new FileInputStream (stock); 
            ObjectInputStream inObjectStream = new ObjectInputStream(inFileStream);
            stck = (Vector <Stock>)inObjectStream.readObject(); 
            inObjectStream.close();
        }else{
            FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(stock);
            ObjectOutputStream outObject = new ObjectOutputStream(outFile);
            outObject.close();
        }
    }catch (IOException io ){
        System.out.println ("Error Loading Stock Database!");
        sc.next();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException c){
        System.out.println ("Error Loading Database! Class not found!!");
        sc.next();
    }

    try{
        if(employee.exists() == true){
            FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream (employee); 
            ObjectInputStream inObject = new ObjectInputStream(inFile);
            emp = (Vector <Employee>)inObject.readObject(); 
            inObject.close();
        }else{
            FileOutputStream outStr = new FileOutputStream(employee);
            ObjectOutputStream outObj = new ObjectOutputStream(outStr);
            outObj.close();
        }
    }catch (IOException io ){
        System.out.println ("Error Loading Employee Database!");
        sc.next();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException c){
        System.out.println ("Error Loading Database! Class not found!");
        sc.next();
    }

    try{
        if(clients.exists() == true){
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream (clients); 
            ObjectInputStream inObjct = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            clt = (Vector <Clients>)inObjct.readObject(); 
            inObjct.close();
        }else{
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(clients);
            ObjectOutputStream outObjct = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
            outObjct.close();
        }
    }catch (IOException io ){
        System.out.println ("Error Loading Clients Database!");
        sc.next();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException c){
        System.out.println ("Error Loading Database! Class not found!");
        sc.next();
    }


//at the end of the runner class.
try{
        FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(stock);
        ObjectOutputStream outObject = new ObjectOutputStream(outFile);
        outObject.writeObject(stck);
        outObject.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println ("Error writing to Database!");
        sc.next();
    }

    try{
        FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(employee);
        ObjectOutputStream outObject = new ObjectOutputStream(outFile);
        outObject.writeObject(emp);
        outObject.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println ("Error writing to Database!");
        sc.next();
    }

    try{
        FileOutputStream outF = new FileOutputStream(clients);
        ObjectOutputStream outObjct = new ObjectOutputStream(outF);
        outObjct.writeObject(clt);
        outObjct.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println ("Error writing to Database!");
        sc.next();
    }
```

Comment: It should be `toString()` instead of `ToString()`.

Comment: Where is the code that stores the object to a file?

Comment: show us your client code.

Comment: @Eran In the main method class.   I updated the code and added the extra code to write the data to the file.

Comment: We want to see how you instantiated your class and saved it.

Comment: @nebula I added some code to read and write to/from the file.

Comment: How is `emp` created?

Comment: @nebula  `Vector <Employee> emp = new Vector <Employee>();`   `Employee tempe = new Employee();`  `tempe.addEmployee(emp);`

That is the code in the runner class related to the whole object Employee. 

`Employee e1 = new Employee (n, surname, dateb, address, telephone, mobile, empid);
        temp.add(e1);`  in method addProduct, (which takes `Vector<Employee>temp` in its parameter) I put this code too, `Employee e1 = new Employee (n, surname, dateb, address, telephone, mobile, empid);
        temp.add(e1);` in order to add the data to the vector.

Comment: It's possible that `if(employee.exists() == true)` condition is not met and `emp` was not set.

Comment: `stock.exists() == true` is redundant.  That can be simplified to `if (stock.exists())`

Comment: Why are you writing a `File` object to a file?  `outObject.writeObject(stck);`  `stck` is an instance of `java.io.File`.  Is this really what you intended?

Comment: `clt` is set to the deserialized form of the contents of `Clients.dat` if and only if `Clients.dat` exists.  You then write it to `Clients.dat`, but it's unclear what `clt` is set to if the file does not exist.  Since you did not show any instances of it being set, my assumption is that it's `null`.

Comment: @nebula Those are forward slashes.

Comment: stck is the vector storing the stock details. The problem is with the employee and client because the data is being stored as blank strings.

Comment: @Brandon yeah. noticed and removed the comment.

Comment: @Brandon Sorry but I didn't really understand what you meant. Still new to java. Is it possible if you clarify please ?

Comment: @DavidFarrugia Why wouldn't it be blank strings?  The code in your question never sets the properties.  In your comment, you showed the code which creates the objects and it uses the no-arg constructor.

Comment: The `File` class represents the path to a file.  It's an abstraction to make it easy to check if a file exists, what type it is, etc.  That is what you are writing to the contents of the file, is that `File` object itself.

Comment: I have a couple suggestions: 1) Remove the no-arg constructor and force clients to set the values. The problem you are seeing with the empty file is because you are constructing an object with blank fields and never bother to overwrite these values. 2) Inside the constructor, check for blank or null and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if any parameter contains an illegal value. Of course, document this on the constructor Javadoc comment.

Remember that objects in Java are initialized to `null` and that a `String` is an object. Primitives are initialized to a value of 0.

Comment: @Brandon So what shall I do inorder to use the overloaded constructor and actually set the properties? Shouldn't it be used automatically since I passed arguements to the object ?

Comment: But you're not passing arguments to the object.  That's the problem.

Comment: `Employee e1 = new Employee (name, sname, dob, address, tel, mob, empid);`
`temp.add(e1);`
 `System.out.println ("Employee was Added Succesfully!");`

Ok so I have to add this right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Employee` is serializable, but `Person` is not.  What that means is that the fields inherited from Person are not being serialized (that is, they are not being written to the ObjectOutputStream) and will not be filled in during deserialization (that is, reading from an ObjectInputStream).

The easiest way to fix this is to make Person implement Serializable.  Note that the interface is inherited, so if you do make that change, you can safely remove `implements Serializable` from the Employee class.

If that isn't an option, you will have to do the work yourself in your Employee class.  That's rather involved for someone new to Java, so I'd rather not clutter this answer with the details, but if you need to go this route I can elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct in terms of inheritence, the "problem" seems to be in the way you're using it.

How are you instanciating each employee? 
Are you using the constructor with parameters? You have to use that one when you re-run your program, otherwise you'll be instantiating blank empoloyees as you describded.

Comment: `Vector <Employee> emp = new Vector <Employee>();`   `Employee tempe = new Employee();`  `tempe.addEmployee(emp);`

That is the code in the runner class related to the whole object Employee. 

`Employee e1 = new Employee (n, surname, dateb, address, telephone, mobile, empid);
        temp.add(e1);`  in method addProduct, (which takes `Vector<Employee>temp` in its parameter) I put this code too, `Employee e1 = new Employee (n, surname, dateb, address, telephone, mobile, empid);
        temp.add(e1);` in order to add the data to the vector.

Comment: Since I am passing arguements into the constructor shouldn't the overloaded constructor be used?

Answer (score 0):

To serialize members of super class this Person class should also implements Serializable.

```
 public class Person implements Serializable {
 ...
```

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410840/serialization-with-super-class-and-sub-class) then Employee class will automatically implements Seralizable.